# Install magento 2 and setup sahara theme

Tags: php, magento2

Installed Sahara theme with quick installation but i get some error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config.php(345): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config->getSerializer() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Config->extend(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Objec in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-store\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 50

any one face this issue earlier so please tell me who i fix this issue i am very stuck in this issue

Comment: Check here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125415/magento-2-installation-fatal-error-cannot-instantiate-interface

Comment: i added this code in page end root $MAGE_ROOT; in pub/index.php but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands and check

```
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: when i run these commands again show this error in command line